# How to load bootstrap script and style in functions.php (wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I converted bootstrap theme to wordpress. Now, I have a problem in loading the bootstrap scripts and style.
This is my code in functions.php

```
   function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
    {

        // Register the script like this for a theme:
        wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'samplejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array( '' ) );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'samplejs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/clean-blog.min.js', array( '' ) );
        // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

and i add this in my header

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

Additional question:
What is the difference between wp_register and wp_enqueue?
Please help me. Im beginner in using bootstrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is enqueue them. Also, I recommend getting rid of your jquery import (the second wp_enqueue). WordPress includes jQuery by default, and you're already including it in the first script (because you have listed it as a dependency). Here's an example, but this enqueues jquery twice (the native jquery, and the bootstrap jquery):

```
function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'blog-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/clean-blog.min.js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

The only reason you'd need to register the scripts before enqueue-ing them, is if one of the scripts is a dependency. From the docs:

> wp_register_script() registers a script file in WordPress to be linked
>   to a page later using the wp_enqueue_script() function, which safely
>   handles the script dependencies.
>
> Scripts that have been pre-registered using wp_register_script() do
>   not need to be manually enqueued using wp_enqueue_script() if they are
>   listed as a dependency of another script that is enqueued. WordPress
>   will automatically include the registered script before it includes
>   the enqueued script that lists the registered script's handle as a
>   dependency.

Comment: thank you very much @rnevius :) how about the styles?

Comment: I've edited my answer with more of an explanation. For enqueueing styles, you can include them in the same way, within that same function, using `wp_enqueue_style`.

Comment: Try changing the array in the `'custom-script'` enqueue to `array('bootstrap-jquery')`. That way, your scripts wait until the second script is enqueued (assuming you named it the way I did above).

Comment: I used contact form 7 for my contact page form, because of the changes its not working, its really had a jquery conflict. then how to solve this? thank you very much @rnevius

Comment: @rnevius, why the use of the function get_stylesheet_directory_uri for non-stylesheet files?  Is it just a poorly named WP function?

Comment: @RobertByers , this function would have been better named something like `get_theme_root_uri()`, since it returns the theme root of the current active theme, even if it's a child theme. On the flip side, `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the root of the parent theme, even if a child theme is active. I would have named that function something like `get_parent_theme_root_uri()`. These two functions are identical if the active theme is not a child theme.

Comment: More back story: WordPress expects the default stylesheet to exist in the theme root...so returning that stylesheet's "directory URI" gives you the theme root. Oddly named...but makes sense, if you understand that WordPress convention.

Comment: @rnevius, ah, got ya.  It seemed to imply something like that. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

you cas use "wp_enqueue_style" and "wp_enqueue_script".

for example:

```
function reg_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapthemestyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'reg_scripts');
```

Comment: thanks @elnaz :) actulally its working now, but the contact form 7 is not working due to jquery conflict. please help me solve this.